# Watson Personality insight minimum number of words required Issue

Tags: watson, watson-personality-insights

I'm following [this](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix-Docs/personality-insights/blob/master/getting-started.md) Personality insight starter but always get below error message for API call

```
{"help":"http:\/\/www.ibm.com\/smarterplanet\/us\/en\/ibmwatson\/developercloud\/doc\/personality-insights\/#overviewInput","code":400,"sub_code":"S00014","error":"The number of words 2 is less than the minimum number of words required for analysis: 100"}
```

Here is the curl request

```
curl -X POST --user xxxx:yyyy --header "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8" --data-binary "profile.txt" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2017-11-14"
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personality insights requires a minimum of 100 words to work. But you won’t get a true insight until around 1,200 words (IIRC).

It’s telling you that you only supplied two words. If this isn’t the case, ensure that you JSON data is correctly escaped.

Comment: Just adding, 3000 words gives the best results, more than that is ignored, but at 600 you can already get good information.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but, no one seems to have added the answer. Just in case, someone also encountered the same error, the issue is missing "@" while specifying the file from which the content has to be read. 
From "man curl" on ubuntu 16.04
```
       --data-binary 
              (HTTP) This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever.

```
          If  you  start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a filename.  Data is posted in a similar manner as --data-ascii
          does, except that newlines and carriage returns are preserved and conversions are never done.
```

```

So, the request should have been 

`curl -X POST --user xxxx:yyyy --header "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8" --data-binary "@profile.txt" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2017-11-14"`